# How can I wait for a (TPL) Task to start?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

After starting a new task with

```
Task waitUntilSaved = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ... });
```

how can I wait until it is started? I.e. I want to continue only in the flow when I know the task has started and `waitUntilSave.Status` equals `TaskStatus.Running`.

Or is this kind of meaningless, because the task might have started without actually executing the first statement?

EDIT:
Yes, I do want to make sure that the first statement is called. Here's my scenario. I have a Web UI which I test drive through Selenium. There's one element (widget) that is shown *while* the UI is doing a save operation. In the test I want to make sure that

A) The widget appears while saving.

B) Continue with the test once the widget is invisible again (and thus saving has completed).

For this I wrote:

```
        Task waitUntilSaved = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Driver.FindElementOrNull(By.Id("isSavingPosition"), FindBehavior.WaitUntilDisplayed);
                Driver.FindElement(By.Id("isSavingPosition"), FindBehavior.WaitUntilHidden);
            });
        Thread.Sleep(10); // how can I get rid of this?
        Assert.AreEqual(TaskStatus.Running, waitUntilSaved.Status);
        saveButton.Click();
        waitUntilSaved.Wait();
```

The first statement of the task will stop the task and wait until the widget is displayed. The second statement of the task simply waits until the widget disappears again.

The first statement after starting the task - the very ugly one I want to get rid of - is making sure (or rather increasing the chance) that the first statement of the task gets executed *before* clicking the save button.

If `saveButton.Click` gets executed too early, the task might fail to catch the appearance *and* disappearance of the "is saving"-widget and thus halt the task forever.

Comment: It does sound meaningless.

Comment: Not really sure about your question, [`StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) "Creates and **starts** a task."

Comment: @Habib `StartNew` schedules the task for execution. It might be executed a fraction of a second later. I think he wants to wait until it has been actually started, i.e., the first instruction of the lambda has been executed. I personally don't see the point of doing this, not without any context.

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming.  The task will start, but it makes no guarantees as to when.  It will also finish, but it makes no guarantees as to when or what its state will be.  The `Task` object itself provides some ways to hook into it (such as `.ContinueWith` for example) with callbacks to check its progress.

Comment: It's very likely you're trying to solve the wrong problem. With more context it would likely be possible to find a much better solution.

Comment: I've added more context to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is meaningless because the thread the task runs on can be paused by the OS at any time. It can be paused directly after you have determined that it is started.

Probably, your synchronization scheme needs rethinking.

Comment: I've added more context to my question. As you can see, I actually want to pause the task after the first statement :)

Comment: Ok, now this makes sense because the question is "How to wait until a certain statement is done?". Look into the Barrier class. Have child and parent thread SignalAndWait. The docs will probably explain this class well.

Comment: Or, split the task into two and wait for the first task to complete before moving on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like this:

```
    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    Task waitUntilSaved = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        mre.Set();

    });

    mre.WaitOne();

    // code after...
```

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but there's a pitfall: if the `Task` is scheduled to run on the same context as the thread that created it, this will lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @dcastro: yep, you are right, but there are ways to ensure that the task is running in a different context as the thread that created it...